# Incremental search in Visual studio 2015 - no indication?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, visual-studio-2015

I'm using vs2015 (pro) , (with Resharper 2016 installed).

Incremental search : the ability to search text via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

With previous versions of Visual studio ( 2010 for example) , when I searched something with incremental search - Visual studio used to show me if there are no matches (while typing):

Vs2010 :

[image]

But when i'm doing it with Visual studio 2015 : (let's search "love" with `ctrl+i`) :

Vs2015:

[image]

See? no indication at all.

**Question**

How can I make incremental search work as it should ( at least - to show me - no matches).

Im tagging this question also as resharper , since i don't know if it's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border of my search window goes red when no matches are found but not sure why yours hasn't. I am using the dark theme if that makes a difference.

[image]

I don't think this is related to ReSharper at all as it is default Visual Studio functionality.